# Spring boot actuator 2 metrics from custom function

Tags: metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I am in the `spring-boot-actuator` world mow...

How can I add my own **metrics** coming **from a custom function** **from my @Service class**?

I would expect to have something like

```
meterRegistry.registerNewGauge(
    "animals_count",
    "cats",
    animalCounterService::countCatsFromDatabase
);
```

currently i can only find easy metrics like

```
meterRegistry.counter("animals_count").increment();
```

but that doesn't help much when I have to aggregate things like database entries. I need a more flexible one.
I also found something like `MeterBinder.bindTo` but that didn't worked. No error, nothing in metrics.
I am searching now for months without any success.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Micrometer for metrics, right?

If so, you can create a gauge and bind it to any object that provides a method that returns double like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
...
   public double calculateValueForGauge() {...}
}

MyService service = ...// get from spring
MeterRegistry registry = ... // get from spring


// here is how you can create a gauge and bind it to an arbitrary method of your service
Gauge.builder("some.name.goes.here, service, (service) -> service.calculateValueForGauge())
          .register(registry);
```

For example you can place the code of gauge registration to the listener that will be called when the application context is started:

```
@EventListener
public void onApplicationStarted(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
  // register gauges here
}
```

Comment: this is working great :) it just was totally new to me that metrics has no values anymore, you have to go to each /metrics/metric-name by your self

So i enabled /prometheus but there aren't my custom metrics. Do you know how I can migrate these to /prometheus as well?